# How do I disable and enable list items depending on the filter in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is what I've created: http://jsfiddle.net/zidski/ktSA9/

I want to enable and disable the links depending on the filter - 'All Years' starts off disabled as all the years are showing - if I click on 2010 All years should become enabled and so on.

```
<ul name="yearfilter" id="yearfilter">
<li value=""><a data-value="" href="#" class="disable">All years</a></li>
<li value="2011"><a data-value="2011" href="#">2011</a></li>
<li value="2010"><a data-value="2010" href="#">2010</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ktSA9/4/

Pertinent change:

```
$("#yearfilter a").removeClass("disable");
$(this).addClass("disable");
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
$("#yearfilter a").bind('click', function() {
    $("#yearfilter a").removeClass('disable');
    $(this).addClass('disable');
});
```

EDIT: Changed the above to bind to the anchor elements instead of the list items.

Essentially you just need to add the following two lines to your existing function:

```
$("#yearfilter a").removeClass('disable');
$(this).addClass('disable');
```

Comment: The disable class is on the A element within the LI.

Comment: remove disable class from anchor not li.

Comment: Thanks gents, obvious mistake on my part.

Answer (score 0):

Check this 
http://jsfiddle.net/ktSA9/2/